# Finding war record of Karl Weber who was German WW2 POW based in England?

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-2

I'm looking for information on a German POW based taken to a camp in England during WW2. His name was Karl Weber I believe at some point he was based in Nuneaton. He could speak English and was the 'go between' at the camp. He was a talented artist and sculptor and there is still a sculpture of his in England. He had a very good friendship with my grandmother who was a WAAF nurse. And he drew an amazing portrait of her which I have hanging in my house. I would really like to know what happened to him after the war. I cannot find him on Ancestry or Findmypast.

Does anyone know where else I could look?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.